# List items separator in Android

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I need a list separator as below. Could anyone help me with how I can achieve this?

[image]

Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Sowmya.

Comment: You want that stright line or a circle??

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: It is a straight line. with two shades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then write Line shape like this..and apply those two color codes and set it to the listview..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:bottom="-2dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="line" >
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#006064"
            android:startColor="#006064" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5):

Set your listview property as

```
android:divider="@color/lightGreyColor"
```

and you can adjust the divider height as

```
android:dividerHeight="2dp"
```

color code for lightGrey = `#ececec`

you also make it gradient by using gradient resource.